# Multiplicative identity of a quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring such that $M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$. Then I know that $R/M$ is a field.

But I am unable to understand what is the multiplicative identity of $R/M$?

If $R$ has an identity then, I think the identity has to be $M+1$. Also if $a\in R$ then what is the inverse of $M+a$?

Comment: If $R$ does not have an identity, $R/M$ need not be a field. Consider $R=2\mathbb Z$ and $M=4\mathbb Z$. - And if $a\notin M$, then $(M,a)=R$ hence $1\in (M,a)$, i.e. there exists $b\in R$, $m\in M$ such that $1=m+ab$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about the multiplicative identity. As for the multiplicative inverse of $ M+a $; if $ a $ has a multiplicative inverse in $ R $ then it is $ M + a^{-1} $. Otherwise the inverse is some element $ M+b $ such that $ ab \in M+1 $.